# eclipse does not open my Javafx project

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

My problem is when in an open javafx project and try to run it without editing it, an error appear like this, and everything install for java FX.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check whether your getClass().getResource() call actually returns a non-null value. I assume your css-file is not in the right place.

Comment: but how to solve this error . what should i use instead of this?
by the way this created by eclipse by default !!

Comment: It is not created by Eclipse but by the e(fx)clipse plugin when you explicitly create a JavaFX-project. But anyway your example indeed looks like this default project and this should run without problems. At least it does so on my machine. Is there anything wrong with the css-file? Can you open and edit it?

Comment: my css file is empty ... i wounder what is wrong exactly ... i comment the getclass which bring css file to project and it is running , and i do not any editing to project !!!!!